# How to unit test a function that return JSX.element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, tdd

I have a function that accepts a parameter and returns a `JSX.Element`

```
//title.tsx
export const getTitle = (pageTitle: string) => {
    return <title> {pageTitle} </title>;
}
```

This is how I'm testing it:

```
describe('Title component', () => {    
    test("Title component is rendered", () => {
        const wrapper = getTitle('abc');
        const expectedText = `abc`;
        const actualText = wrapper; //wrapper.text() does not exists;
        expect(actualText).toContain(expectedText);
    });
});
```

The test fails with the following output:

```
Expected value: "abc"
Received object: <React.Fragment><title>abc</title></React.Fragment>
```

As per some research, I found a solution on Google, which assumes that the function is part of a class component. The solution requires [`wrapper`](https://medium.com/@relasine/testing-component-methods-that-return-jsx-in-react-dc8032e3cf22) to be an [returned by `shallow` while passing the class-based component `ControlledForm`)](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-basics-of-testing-a-react-component-2ff635c99044). This does not apply to my case.

> How to extract the text value out of `JSX.element` returned by the function to compare with some expected text?

Or is there another way to test such cases?

Comment: I started writing up an answer for you but realize it doesn't address your core issue to write a correct test. I'll work on that part. In the meantime, let's get some terminology straight: `getTitle()` is a function that returns JSX, but it is **not** a functional component. A functional component must take a single JavaScript object as its only parameter. Traditionally we call this parameter `props`. The main difference is that you cannot use `<getTitle>` as a JSX tag like you could if you wrote it correctly as a functional component. Instead, you have to call `getTitle()` directly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 4):

Go for the props or use another shallow. I don't know which one is the red pill.

```js
const titleName = "titleName";
const wrapper = shallow(getTitle(titleName));
const titleElement = wrapper.getElement("title");
titleElement.props.children[1] // "titleName" as [0] and [2] are " "
const containsTitle = titleElement.props.children.includes(titleName);
expect(containsTitle).toBe(true);
```

or

```js
const titleName = "titleName";
const wrapper = shallow(getTitle(titleName));
const titleElement = wrapper.getElement("title");
const secondWrapper = shallow(titleElement);
secondWrapper.text() // "titleName"
const containsTitle = secondWrapper.contains(titleName);
expect(containsTitle).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate props part of your answer? Please...

Comment: You mean the first one? When you wrap JSX in JSX stuff is being put in `props.children`

Comment: ReactShallowRenderer render(): Shallow rendering works only with custom components, but the provided element type was `symbol`.

Comment: @ZameerAnsari could you suggest how did you solve this ? I also facing the exact same issue.
Testing react component that returns another Child Component or jsx.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to provide an alternative answer for anyone using Testing Library:

```js
// This code snippet won't run, but will work in a project

import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

describe('Title component', () => {    
    test("Title component is rendered", () => {
        const actualText = "abc"
        const {getByText} = render(<>{getTitle(actualText)}</>);
        expect(getByText(actualText, {selector: "title"})).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Depending on what you're testing, you could also use, e.g., `getByRole`, and then assert on the content / `textContent` of the returned portion of the rendered DOM. And there are certainly other strategies that could work.